# read type of Group object - group in h5py.Group object

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

```
def select_HDF_file(self):
        filename2 = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.dlg, "Select output file","",'*.hdf')
        file = h5py.File(filename2 , 'r')

        dataset = []

        for i in file.values():
            dataset.append(i)

        Grp = h5py.Group
        Grp = dataset[3]
        Grp2 = Grp.<<idont know how to access group in group>>
        Gname = Grp.name
```

I read HDF file in python and read group in HDF file too like this

```
Grp = h5py.Group
```

but I don't know one more group in `grp`.

How can I read this group?

Comment: You already have group inside your dataset. I do not understand what you want to do.

Comment: thanks i can handle this

Comment: Then mark the question as answered if you have it.

Answer (score 0):

You already have group inside your dataset. If you want to know what method are available for the object, you can do:

```
print(dir(dataset[3]))
[..., 'name', ...]
```

You will found `name` as expected.